# Show username on mac terminal prompt

Tags: macos

My OSX El Capitan terminal prompt is "~$". As I am logged in as a user.
How can I get it to show the machine~user$ instead? Thanks

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14416556/322020

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your shell is `bash` edit the `/etc/bashrc` file changing `PS1='\W\$ '` to:

`PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '`

You'll need to use `sudo`, e.g., `sudo nano /etc/bashrc`

On OS X 10.11 you might also need to disable [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) in order to make the edit.

Otherwise setting it in your `̃/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file, either of which, you'd not have to use `sudo` or disable SIP to edit.

**Explanation:**

```
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '

PS1 The value of this parameter is expanded (see PROMPTING below) and used as the primary prompt string.
=   equals
'   single quote
\h  the hostname up to the first ‘.’
:   colon
\W  the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
    white space
\u  the username of the current user
\$  if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
    white space
'   single quote

Examples:

MacBookPro:~ user$
MacBookPro:Documents user$
MacBookPro:~ root#
```

See the `PROMPT_COMMAND` and `PROMPTING` sections in the OS X Man Pages for [BASH(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) for more information on the subject.

Comment: What is an "effective UID"? **UPD:** nvm, found it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32456814/322020