# What is the @ symbol in my terminal prompt? Where does this come from?

Tags: terminal, macos

In my [research](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224149/show-username-on-mac-terminal-prompt) on command prompts, the examples all seems to show the computer name and username as the only thing at the "prompt", ie `MacBookPro:Documents user$`

However when I open terminal, the prompt reads:

```
codybugstein@TL-WA855RE ~ %
```

Where does this come from? How is it generated? What is the `@` sign? And why is my router model in there?

Thanks!

Comment: Which shell are you using (`echo $0` if you don't know)? Are you wondering about the prompt as a whole or just your router name in there? What have you already done in terms of research on "terminal prompt"?

Comment: `echo $0` gives me `/bin/zsh`

Comment: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-06-customizing-the-zsh-prompt/

Comment: Hmm this still doesn't explain how my router's model # got in there...